# Append to a string in an infinite iteration inside a windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to iterate each byte received over UDP and append that byte to a string (sbCardNo). The problem is the iteration for each byte is in the while loop, meaning a infinate loop (if I understand this correctly). How can I adapt the below code to add each byte to a string?

```
private void DoWork()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
        UdpClient newsock = new UdpClient(ipep);

        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        StringBuilder sbCardNo = new StringBuilder();

        while (true)
        {
            data = newsock.Receive(ref sender);

            sbCardNo.Append(data.GetValue(0));

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderPath + "\\AuthService.txt",
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            StreamWriter m_streamwriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            m_streamwriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            m_streamwriter.WriteLine(sbCardNo);

            m_streamwriter.Flush();
            m_streamwriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

The above code gives me the following -

```
2
252
25267
2526748
252674848
25267484870
2526748487069
25267484870693
```

I just need the last line - 25267484870693

Thanks

Comment: "I just need the last line"? How is the last line different from, say, the penultimate line? How do you know when you've arrived?

Comment: If the sender is sending datagrams that consist of a single byte, then you'll need an "end of message" byte so you know when to break out of the loop. The better solution is to have the sender send the entire value in a single datagram. Also, look into the [StreamWriter constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) that lets you open for append.

Comment: The end byte is always a 3 if that helps?

Comment: That helps, maybe. Is it possible that `3` will exist in any position other than the end byte? If you know that `3` is always the last byte and that it never exists in the rest of the string, then you can read and append in a loop and break after you've received the `3`.

Comment: The start byte is always a 2, the end byte is always a 3. Each byte between is double digits. It may contain a 3, but never alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the file at the end of the **while** and write all the contents of the **StringBuilder** at once, and handle logic for possible excpetions

In this example its reading until the byte 'Z' is received, but is much better if the other side of this comunication sends a single String or that the first 2 bytes is the length of the bytes that will be sent

```
private void DoWork()
{
    byte ch ;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
    UdpClient newsock = new UdpClient(ipep);

    IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    StringBuilder sbCardNo = new StringBuilder();

    while (true)
    {
        do
        {
            data = newsock.Receive(ref sender);
            ch = data.GetValue(0)
            sbCardNo.Append(ch);
        } while (ch != 'Z') ;

        using (StreamWriter m_streamwriter = new StreamWriter( folderPath + "\\AuthService.txt"))
        {
            m_streamwriter.WriteLine(sbCardNo.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, however the service is then unable to accept any other UDP commands for some reason?

Comment: @MattBaughan are you getting and expection ? can you debug it and tell me exactly in which line stops working ? keep in mind that I removed the Infinite loop when receiving, maybe you received a "Z" and the service stopped receiving ?

Comment: There are no exceptions reported. The service continues to run, however it looks like because there is no loop checking for incoming UDP, it does not write any more UDP strings to the text file. Cheers

Comment: @MattBaughan I just added a "while (true) loop" but I think this protocol has room for improvements

Comment: Perfect, only change I made is replacing the file modification - FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderPath + "\\AuthService.txt",
                FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

                StreamWriter m_streamwriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
                m_streamwriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                m_streamwriter.WriteLine(sbCardNo);

                m_streamwriter.Flush();
                m_streamwriter.Close();